# ¿Como eliminar la posición de un vector bidimensional con datos vacíos y re acomodar su tamaño?

Tags: javascript, php, array, matrices-asociativas

Tengo un vector en el cual intento eliminar los espacios que se encuentran vacíos en su totalidad, algo así:

```
array[0][0:"6371", 1:"2016-05-31", 2:"Juan Jose  Mendoza"];
array[1][0:"", 1:"", 2:""];
array[2][0:"6372", 1:"2016-05-31", 2:"Andrea Marcela Pena"];
```

lo que busco es la forma de eliminar la linea que esta vacía y re acomodar el vector de una forma sencilla (sin necesidad de recorrerlo o algo por el estilo) ya sea en [php](/questions/tagged/php) o [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) el resultado final seria algo así:

```
array[0][0:"6371", 1:"2016-05-31", 2:"Juan Jose  Mendoza"];
array[1][0:"6372", 1:"2016-05-31", 2:"Andrea Marcela Pena"];
```

donde la posición `array[1][0:"", 1:"", 2:""];` al tener todos sus campos vacíos se removerá y re acomodaríamos el vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí dejo una alternativa sin necesidad de atravesar el array completo. La idea es la siguiente: convierte el array a una cadena, elimina los elementos vacíos, convierte la cadena de nuevo en un array.

El código podría ser así:

```js
var miArray = new Array();
    
miArray[0] = {0:"6371", 1:"2016-05-31", 2:"Juan Jose  Mendoza"};
miArray[1] = {0:"", 1:"", 2:""};
miArray[2] = {0:"", 1:"", 2:""};
miArray[3] = {0:"6372", 1:"2016-05-31", 2:"Andrea Marcela Pena"};

console.log(miArray);

var texto = JSON.stringify(miArray)                      // transformar en cadena
                .replace(/{"0":"","1":"","2":""}/g, "")  // eliminar elementos vacíos
                .replace(/(\}(,)+\{)/g,"},{");           // quitar comas innecesarias

miArray = JSON.parse(texto);

console.log(miArray);
```

Comment: Aunque la verdad, no sé cómo de eficiente sería esta solución y seguramente pueden mejorarse mis expresiones regulares :$

Comment: La verdad es una solución muy ingeniosa muchas gracias

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro la dificultad de la solución reside en armar correctamente la expresión regular que captura el objeto buscado. En cuanto a eficicia habría que ver que pasa en estructuras más grandes y si tienes muchos registros

Answer (score 3):

Si entendí bien, tienes un `Array` que contiene `Objetos`, "`Array-like Objects`" y quieres filtrar ese array eliminando las posiciones cuyos objetos están completamente vacíos. Puedes usar el siguiente código :

```js
var array = [
  {0:"6371", 1:"2016-05-31", 2:"Juan Jose  Mendoza"},
  {0:"", 1:"", 2:""},
  {0:"6372", 1:"2016-05-31", 2:"Andrea Marcela Pena"}
];

var estanTodosLosElementosDelArrayVacios = function(obj){
  return Object
          //.values(obj)
          .keys(obj).map( el => obj[el] )
          .filter( el => el.length )
          .length;
}

var filtrado = array.filter(estanTodosLosElementosDelArrayVacios);

console.log(filtrado);
```

Comment: Si el javascript corre en un navegador `Object.values` podría no estar definida de acuerdo a la documentación de Mozilla [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: Cierto, lo escribí así por brevedad, puedes hacerlo con `Object.key(obj).map( el => obj[el]);`